# Undefined property Functions sucess Warning

Tags: php

I have a problem with this code, this warning always appears, I'm new and I didn't find a solution could they help?

The following error appears: Undefined property: Functions :: $ _ Sucess C: /xampp/htdocs/cash/index.php on line 14
for the code:

```
<?php 

require_once('class/functions.class.php');

$_Func = new Functions();

if($_Func->_Error) require_once('error.php');


else if($_Func->_Sucess) require_once('sucess.php');


else if(!$_Func->isLogged) require_once('login.php');

else if(!$_Func->isLogged)
  require_once('login.php');

else {if(@$_GET['page'] == 'donate')
    require_once('donate.php');
  
else if(@$_GET['item'])
    require_once('info.php');
  
else
    require_once('loja.php');
}


?>
```

Comment: What is inside file 'class/functions.class.php' ?

Comment: `$this->_Sucess = "Parabéns! Sua compra foi bem sucedida</br>`

Comment: the part that refers to success is this

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> Undefined property: Functions :: $ _ Sucess C: /xampp/htdocs/cash/index.php on line 14

Tells you all you need to know. In this case that the property `_Sucess` is not part of the object `$_Func`.

It looks as though that's a typo and should be:

```
$_Func->_Success
```

Answer (score 0):

The error persists, the sucess.php would be this:

```
<?php if(!$_Func)return false; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Market</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
        <style type="text/css">
html{
  overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    margin:0;
    font-family:Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:url(images/mail.jpg) no-repeat;
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}

</style>
  <body>
      <img src="" />
    <div class="bar-center"></div>
    <div id="content"> 
      <div class="title"></div>
      <div class="form">
        <div class="erro">
          <big><big><big><big><font color=\"#FF0000\">SUCESS</font></big></big></big></big><br><br>
          <span class="tarea">
            <?php echo $_Func->_Sucess;?>
          </span>
                <div class="return">
        <a href="?page=home">
              <img src="img/botton-03.gif" width="159" height="42" name="Image3" border="0">
    
        </div>
      </div>

        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add new information to the question by editing it (link is at the bottom of the question), not through answers.